# div showing directly even after adding delay()

Tags: jquery

Im trying to toggle a div to display and disappear when hovering on the parent container.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".bubble-wrapper").mouseout(function(){
    $(".bubble_news_text").hide(0);
  }).mouseover(function(){
    $(".bubble-wrapper:hover .bubble_news_text").delay(1000).show(500);
  });

});
```

It shows directly even tho I added delay(1000)

Thats my Html:

```
            <div class="bubble-wrapper">
          <li class="breaking_news_bubble">
            <a class="breaking_news_bubble_link" href="#">
              <img src="images/fire.jpg" alt="">
            </a>

            <div class="bubble_news_text">
              <h2 class="bubble_news_title">L.A under heat!</h2>
              <p class="bubble_news_exerpt">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque elit massa...
              </p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </div>
```

Comment: I removed the delay() and turned the show(500) to show(1000) but its still the same :/

Comment: Everything appears to be working correctly to me, I just made a fiddle of this (http://jsfiddle.net/dcm95v2q/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just pass the length of the animation to `.show()` and/or `.hide()`

If the animation is too quick, you can increase it by passing a larger integer number, remember it takes the integer as milliseconds, so 500 is only half a second.

Please see documentation:

(http://api.jquery.com/show/)
(http://api.jquery.com/hide/)